# Powershell: Initializing declare of a Recordset Variable

Tags: powershell, ldap

I have code below that RETURNs NULL, I think because I read somewhere that you must first declare the variable being [ref] referenced before calling the function. How to declare a record set before hand?

```
function SearchAD
{
    param([ref]$objRecordSet)

    #has conn,query, etc.... removed for short reading

    $objRecordSet = $objCommand.Execute()

    $SearchAD = $objRecordSet.RecordCount
}


$SearchResults = SearchAD $oGroups 

Write-Host $SearchResults
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of recordset you're referring to, but if you have an existing object of that type and want to know what it is, try this:

```powershell
$existingRecordset.GetType().FullName
```

From there, maybe you can use `New-Object` or directly call its constructor.

Comment: thats about it, the first time I am declaring $oGroups is in that function call. I dont see any Dim in powershell and I needed the $oGroups value and others, i need multiple objects return from ref in that function

Comment: You don't need Dim in Powershell, you can just assign a value to a new variable. If you want a new instance of an object then you might call New-Object. My answer suggested a way to get the class name that you need in case you didn't know what it was.